# How to compile single package in catkin_ws?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the src folder I have many packages. How to compile a single package using catkin_make command??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287556/how-to-compile-single-package-in-catkin_ws?/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see @fivef's answer in #q54178. This is the first result when I perform a search with Google using your title as the search term:

https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+compile+single+package+in+catkin_ws

```
catkin_make --pkg <package-name>
```

For example, building a package named `turtlebot`

```
catkin_make --pkg turtlebot
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0